# Import Python user-module using SPSS syntax

Tags: python, spss

I am running SPSS 23, and i have a python file named `text_wrap.py`

```
import textwrap
def wrap_title(long_text):
    wtext="+\n".join(textwrap.wrap(long_text,55))
    return wtext
```

...which is located on a custom path on my computer, and which I want to call inside the SPSS syntax.
So far I tried:

```
begin program.
import text_wrap
end program.
```

I got `"No module named text_wrap"`. Makes sense, since it is a user module, not stored in the Python folder.
I also tried

```
begin program.
import "c:/Custom_path/text_wrap"
end program.
```

and

```
import "c:/Custom_path/text_wrap.py"
```

but I got `"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"` in all three situations.

The only way I could get the .py file to run was by running it a script from, `"Utilities/Run script"`. But I would like to do this via SPSS syntax

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by adding you script to the python path/the folder with the libraries, then you can import it like any other library.

Comment: I plan to share the module with other people, who may not have writing permissions into the path, nor have the knowledge to edit path. I am looking for a way to simply call a python file, regardless of location or other local settings